# Why doesn't Firefox run as a Wayland app by default?

Tags: firefox, wayland

To fix the blurriness problem with Firefox and fractional scaling on Wayland, I found out one has to run it as a Wayland app, launching it with `MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1`. That raises the question, why isn't this done by default? It's not as if the Ubuntu devs could have possibly overlooked Firefox. Can it cause some problems? I have been running it like this for a while now and it seems to work fine.

I'm using a default 22.04 Ubuntu, running the default Firefox snap. To clarify, Firefox *does* run on Wayland, but as an X app, via `xwayland`, not as a Wayland app, unless I set the environmental variable mentioned above.

Comment: Provide detail on your Ubuntu version, and whether you use the default Firefox or not. On Ubuntu 22.04 at least, Firefox runs natively on Wayland.

Comment: No it doesn't. I've edited the question to clarify.

Comment: You are right indeed - I thought I checked before, but indeed it is running on xwayland.

Comment: A bug is open: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1970884

Comment: Thanks, the but report contains the answer: "Mozilla asked to revert the option until they can do more testing". You can post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Since beginning of august the version `103.0.2` from snap defaults to Wayland. Note that it was still not the case in `103.0.0`.

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me was to switch to beta release in Ubuntu software (currently Firefox Beta 103.0b9-1). It installs a new version of Firefox snap. Runs without problems and is nicely sharp. The only problem is that if you want to go back to stable release Firefox will force you to start a new profile, which means losing bookmarks, passwords etc. (they will remain saved on your computer in the old profile, but it seems that it's not possible to make them work in the stable version again). Easy solution is to have a Firefox account and synchronize.